# ActiveMQ exception when sending messages from Celery

Tags: python, celery, activemq-classic

I am trying to configure

> celery==3.1.24

with

> apache-activemq-5.10.0

inside a python django application.

When I am running the application I get the following exception in the activemq console.

> org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolException: Could not
>   decode AMQP frame: hex: 414d515001010009  at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onFrame(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onAMQPData(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AMQPProtocolDiscriminator.onAMQPData(AMQPProtocolDiscriminator.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpTransportFilter.onCommand(AmqpTransportFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException:
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: AMQP header mismatch
>   value 1, expecting 0. In state: HEADER4   at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportResultFactory$TransportResultImpl.checkIsOk(TransportResultFactory.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.input(TransportImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onFrame(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:230)
>     ... 7 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.TransportException: AMQP header mismatch
>   value 1, expecting 0. In state: HEADER4   at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.FrameParser.input(FrameParser.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.FrameParser.process(FrameParser.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.process(TransportImpl.java:1265)
>     at
>   org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.TransportImpl.processInput(TransportImpl.java:1226)
>     ... 9 more

What may be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think celery supports ActiveMQ.
Here is the [FAQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/faq.html#can-i-use-celery-with-activemq-stomp) for it.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. Celery doesn't support ActiveMQ. I could successfully configure celery with RabbitMQ.